# Unable to determine the principal end

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Important: I have found a plenty of similar questions about  *Unable
 to determine the principal end of relationship. Multiple added
 entities may have the same primary key* exception in SO. I **read it and understand what
 does it mean and why does it occurs.**

However, I can't find where the problem is hidden **particularly in  my models**. I'll be very grateful if you could point what  exactly done wrong.
Models here:

```
public class Faculty : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Specialty> Specialties { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Department : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid ? FacultyId { get; set; }
    public Faculty Faculty { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Specialty> Specialties { get; set; }
}

public class Specialty : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public Guid FacultyId { get; set; }
    public Faculty Faculty { get; set; }
    public Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; } 
}
```

Configuration: mappings here

```
public class DepartmentConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Department>
{
    public DepartmentConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
        Property(p => p.Acronym).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);
        Property(p => p.Description).HasMaxLength(1000);

        HasMany(p => p.Subjects).WithRequired(p => p.Department);
        HasMany(p => p.Employees).WithOptional(p => p.Department);
        HasMany(p => p.Specialties).WithRequired(p => p.Department);
    }
}

public class SpecialtyConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Specialty>
{
    public SpecialtyConfiguration()
    {
        Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
        Property(p => p.Acronym).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);
        Property(p => p.Description).HasMaxLength(1000);
        HasMany(p => p.Students).WithRequired(p => p.Specialty);
    }
}

public class FacultyConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Faculty>
{
    public FacultyConfiguration() : base()
    {
        Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
        Property(p => p.Acronym).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(5);
        Property(p => p.Description).HasMaxLength(1000);

        HasMany(p => p.Departments).WithOptional(p => p.Faculty);
        HasMany(p => p.Specialties).WithRequired(p => p.Faculty);
        HasMany(p => p.Employees).WithOptional(p => p.Faculty);
        HasMany(p => p.Students).WithRequired(p => p.Faculty);
    }
}
```

And exception says about relationship between Departments and Specialties.

> Unable to determine the principal end of the
>   'EMIS.DAL.Context.Department_Specialties' relationship. Multiple added
>   entities may have the same primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem. There were no mistakes in mappings. I forgot, that by using `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` PK added only in moment of saving data to database. However, I was trying to add Specialty to Department that has ID equals to null till it doesn't exist in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is necessary. You can wrap multiple related database actions in a transaction. Inside the transaction you call SaveChanges() and the db will act like it's been updated (you can access generated ID's, etc.), but unless you call Commit() all of the changes will be rolled back when the transaction object goes out of scope.

For example,

```
using (var transaction = myDbContext.BeginTransaction())
{
  InsertFirstThing();
  myDbContext.SaveChanges();

  InsertSecondThing();
  myDbContext.SaveChanges();

  if (EverythingWasSuccessful())
  {
    transaction.Commit();
  }
}
```